# Is TCP's 3-way handshake a kind of mutual authentication?

Tags: authentication, tcp

Assuming no one is able to inspect or MITM in the network. Can I see it as a way to ensure the source IP in packet's header is the real source of the packet, so a kind of authentication ?

Comment: might help https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225076/using-ip-as-authentication

Comment: _"Assuming no one is able to inspect or MITM in the network"_. That's a really strong assumption considering that routing layers like BGP and ARP were not designed with security in mind. I suspect that hardening your routing layer to the point that you are confident in this assumption will take a lot more effort than using mutual-auth TLS or VPN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Assumptions

Your server is not on the same network as your client thus not able to create a MITM or sniff traffic.

## Answers

> Is TCP's 3-way handshake a kind of mutual authentication?

I'd say it is, but a relatively weak form of mutual authentication.

> Can I see it as a way to ensure the source IP in packet's header is the real source of the packet, so a kind of authentication ?

In all practical cases, yes, you can rely on the source IP in the packet's header being the real source IP if the sequence number is correct and there is no MITM.  Sequence numbers can be anything from 0 to 32^2-1. It is highly unlikely that someone can guess that number faster than the real request can get the correct number.

## Recommendation

It seems like you are trying to use the wrong technologies for what you would like.  While they may work, there is a reason you don't use a screwdriver as a hammer.  I'd recommend using TLS for mutual authentication with client and server certificates.